# Map into an object without a temporary variable

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, lodash, ramda.js

How do I map through array of objects and based on that create another object (based on element properties), without temporary object? So if I have something like:

```
 foos = [ { name: 'A' }, { name: 'B' }, { name: 'C' } ]
 objx = {}
 foos.map (x)-> 
     objx[x.name] = 'name is ' + x.name.toLowerCase()

 # objx = { A: 'name is a', B: 'name is b', C: 'name is c' }
```

How can I accomplish the same thing without `objx` thing? 
Either with or without using whatever helper library - lodash, ramda, jquery, angular, etc.

Comment: See [Creating a dictionary Object from an Array](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/creating-a-dictionary-object-from-an-array) also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce` which is built-in by passing an empty object as accumulator:

```
foos.reduce (acc, x) ->
  acc[x.name] = "name is #{x.name.toLowerCase()}"
  acc
,{}
```